# Change format date on Datepicker (material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I want to change the format of the date on `DatePicker` ([material-ui-pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/datepicker)), but when I use the `formatDate` feature, the format of the date does not change and still show only month and date, not the year selected.

This is my code:

```
<DatePicker
  margin="normal"
  disableFuture
  openTo="year"
  views={["year", "month", "day"]}
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={this.handleDateChange}
  maxDate={maxdate}
  formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
/>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The prop for changing the date format is called [`format` and takes a string instead of a function](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/datepicker#component-api).

```
<DatePicker
  margin="normal"
  disableFuture
  openTo="year"
  views={["year", "month", "day"]}
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={this.handleDateChange}
  maxDate={maxdate}
  format="DD-MM-YYYY"
/>
```

Answer (score 14):

2022 method is:

`<DatePicker inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" />`

Comment: It helped me with DateRangePicker from MUI.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It not described correctly (with example) in docs. So many thanks for that info!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<DatePicker inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" views={["day", "month", "year"]} 
value={value} onChange {(newValue) => {setValue(newValue);}} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <label htmlFor="department" className="form-label mb-2">
                Date To
              </label>
              <DatePicker
                className="form-control"
                value={dateTo}
                onChange={handledDateTo}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: needs a bit more explanation and formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                                    <DateTimePicker
                                        renderInput={(props) => <TextField  variant="standard"  className="w-100" required {...props} />}
                                        label="voyage Start Date"
                                        value={formik.values?.voyageStartDate}
                                        onChange={(newValue) => {
                                           formik.setFieldValue("voyageStartDate",moment(newValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
                                        }}
                                        onKeyPress={() => formik.setFieldTouched("voyageStartDate")}
                                    />
                                </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **2022** the solution is `ampm={false}` parameter

```
<DateTimePicker
  ampm={false}
  renderInput={...}
/>
```

Check [mui-x doc](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/)

Comment: I dont think this is correct, the doc you pointed to says that "ampm" is for "12h/24h view for hour selection clock." And specifically the question has nothing to do with time, just dates, in the example from the OP it was about DatePicker only not DateTimePicker...

Answer (score -1):

for 2023 solution try this

```
 <DatePicker
     className="w-160"
     clearable
     slotProps={dateProps('Start Date')}
     format="dd-MM-yy"
    />
```

Your date and year should be in small casae

Comment: This doesn't work just use `format='DD/MM/YY'`